# Firebase C++ SDK. Realtime Database and keepSynced

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

On Android/iOS SDK we can keep specific locations in sync with `databaseRef.keepSynced(true)`. But what about C++ SDK? How we can keep specific location in sync without listeners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same `keepSynced` API exists in the C++ SDK. You can find it in the [API reference docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/cpp/class/firebase/database/query#setkeepsynchronized) for `Query::SetKeepSynced()`:

> ```
> void SetKeepSynchronized(
>   bool keep_sync
> )
> ```

Note that if you ever find an SDK where it doesn't exist, you can easily implement it yourself by attaching an empty listener to the reference/query. That is pretty much the same as what the iOS/Android SDKs do under the hood.